# Is there way to Amazon KVS to lambda data streaming with Amazon connect?

Tags: aws-lambda, speech-recognition, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm using amazon kinesis video stream with lambda on python.

I'm trying to send audio stream to lambda from kvs.

These codes what I was tryed but error says "Source must be an audio source"

First, get stream audio. StreamingBody...

Second, Read da StreamingBody with read() function.

Third, Then I got da bytes data from stream.

At last, Listening bytes audio with SpeechRecognizer. then said "Source must be an audio source".

Please help me...

```py
import io
import boto3
import asyncio
import speech_recognition as sr

kinesis_client = boto3.client("kinesisvideo")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    media_stream = event["Details"]["ContactData"]["MediaStreams"]

    customer_audio = media_stream["Customer"]["Audio"]

    stream_arn = customer_audio["StreamARN"]

    # <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f9c0d849810>
    audio_stream = getMedia(stream_arn)

    record_audio_stream(audio_stream)


def getMedia(streamArn):
    endpoint_response = kinesis_client.get_data_endpoint(
        StreamARN=streamArn, APIName="GET_MEDIA"
    )
    data_endpoint = endpoint_response["DataEndpoint"]

    kinesis_video_client = boto3.client(
        "kinesis-video-media", endpoint_url=data_endpoint
    )

    response = kinesis_video_client.get_media(
        StreamARN=streamArn, StartSelector={"StartSelectorType": "EARLIEST"}
    )

    payload = response["Payload"]

    return payload

def record_audio_stream(self, audio_stream):

    async def recording():
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

        audio_bytes = audio_stream.read()

        with io.BytesIO(audio_bytes) as source:
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
            recognized_text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            print(recognized_text)

    asyncio.run(recording())
```